# Set the width of material UI select based on label size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've got a `select`:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">{this.props.label}</InputLabel> 
    <Select
            native
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange('value')}
        inputProps={{
            name: this.props.label,
            id: this.props.id,
        }}
        >
        {this.buildSelectOptions(this.props.options)}
    </Select>
                        {(this.props.helperText)?<FormHelperText>{this.props.helperText}</FormHelperText>:null}
</FormControl>
```

The formControl class looks like this:

```
formControl: {
    margin: 0,
    fullWidth: true,
    backgroundColor: '#9ee',
    wrap: 'nowrap'
},
```

It works reasonably well - sizing itself to be as small as possible while still showing the largest possible `option` value.

Unfortunately, when the `InputLabel` is longer than the contents of the select `options` ... the label wraps and looks terrible.

How can I keep my select from wrapping the input label?   I'd like it to simply expand the select as needed, as it does when there is a long entry in the `option` list if possible.  Setting a "minWidth" isn't my preferred solution for many reasons (mainly that this component is used by a bunch of different things and calculating the minWidth of them all would be difficult)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question here. I thought the issue was with menu items wrapping which my answer would fix. The correct and simple fix to the question is that you are missing `display: 'flex'` from your formControl class.

Like this:

```
  formControl: {
    margin: 0,
    fullWidth: true,
    backgroundColor: '#9ee',
    display: 'flex',
    wrap: 'nowrap'
  },
```

Here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v0w0mn7xn0)

It looks like `<Select/>` has an `autoWidth` property that you can set to achieve this. It's default is `false`.

From the docs:

> If true, the width of the popover will automatically be set according
>   to the items inside the menu, otherwise it will be at least the width
>   of the select input.

It's used like this:

```
 <Select
    native
    autoWidth={true}
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange('value')}
    inputProps={{
        name: this.props.label,
        id: this.props.id,
    }}
    >
    {this.buildSelectOptions(this.props.options)}
 </Select>
```

Comment: This didn't change the behavior at all.  (and the width is already set according to the items INSIDE the menu... I need it set to the wider between the width of the items inside the menu AND the `InputLabel`)    Ideally, I'd like it to just expand to fit the container it's in....

Comment: Your update, with the `display: 'flex'` change nailed it.  The Select is now as big as it's container.